# How to move out the dynamic result-document into the separate included or imported xsl file

Tags: xslt, doctype, xslt-2.0, saxon, indentation

I have a bunch of xsl files. I want to control an indent of result document centrally. I use now the code below in every xsl file. I have an xsl:template name="data" template in each file, but the content of this template is different. Is it possible to move out the content of xsl:template match="/" into the separate xsl file properly and import it in every xsl file. I tried but to no effect. Can someone advise me a working code?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output name="indent" method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:output name="no_indent" method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="indent" select="//page/view-data/html-indent"/>
    <xsl:if test="$indent='yes'">
     <xsl:result-document format="indent" >
       <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
     </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$indent='no'">
     <xsl:result-document format="no_indent" >
       <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
     </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="data">
   <!-- The content is different from file to file -->
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you can try also xsl:include instruction - in this case templates will have the same priorities as main document

Comment: It doesn't matter, I tried both: xsl:include and xsl:import. No effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have overlooked the fact that there is a much simpler way of doing this.

```
<xsl:param name="indent" select="'no'"/>
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document indent="{$indent}">
    ....
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

and then supply the value of indent as a stylesheet parameter. And in fact there's an even simpler way: you can override the serialisation properties given in the stylesheet with properties supplied from the command line or the Java API: from the command line, just specify !indent=yes or !indent=no.

Comment: Thank for your help Michael, it works! I use my custom jsp tag in web application to transform an xml shot inside jsp with xsl in order to use the latest version of Saxon under the trasformation. However the simpler way is not useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

Move the repeating code into a new .xsl e.g. main.xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output name="indent" method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:output name="no_indent" method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:variable name="indent" select="//page/view-data/html-indent"/>
 <xsl:if test="$indent='yes'">
  <xsl:result-document format="indent" >
    <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="$indent='no'">
  <xsl:result-document format="no_indent" >
    <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
  </xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="data"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then in your other .xsl files simply use xsl:import at the top of your document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:import href="file:///C:/Users/Stefanos/area51/main.xsl"/>
  <!--Other stuff here-->
  <xsl:template match="extra"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And add more code. Hope it helped :)

Comment: The problem in my code is that I use <xsl:template name="data"/>

</xsl:stylesheet> and I cannot move it into the main.xsl file. The "data" template is used in every file but it's content from file to file is different.

Comment: @user1018219 Well if the content is different and you want different processing for it then it should be on separate files. Simple. Or you could account for all possible different contents with a single template with conditionals.

Comment: I tried to leave my different "data" templates in xsl files "as is" (lets say 1.xsl, 2.xsl, 3.xsl) and to move out a code from <xsl:template match="/"> into the separate file e.g. main.xsl. But in this case the call of "data" template from main.xsl brings an error.

Comment: @user1018219 Without the actual code I and noone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after separation, this is a main.xsl . I just simplified here the variable value.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output name="indent" method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:output name="no_indent" method="html" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="indent" select="'yes'"/>
   <xsl:if test="$indent='yes'">
     <xsl:result-document format="indent" >
       <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
     </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test="$indent='no'">
     <xsl:result-document format="no_indent" >
       <xsl:call-template name="data"/>
     </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And next file, let's say 1.xsl

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <xsl:import href="main.xsl"/>

      <xsl:template name="data">
      ...
      </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here, I have an xsl transformation error

Comment: You should have edited your original answer. In any case what exactly is your problem?

Comment: The problem after separation is to call the data template in 1.xsl from main.xsl

Comment: You got it wrong. The 1.xsl will import whatever is inside main.xsl and call whatever templates are need to be called in that .xml and **then** the data template will be called.

Comment: Sounds good but my goal is to apply the xsl:result-document on "data" template which is in 1.xsl what was before in one file before the separation.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean. In my first instance i can call template from xsl:result-document and it works inside my application.  I only want to move out the code with xsl:result-document conditions into the separate file and to have the same behavior.

Comment: I don't see any result-document there. Do you?

Comment: I do. <xsl:result-document format="indent" > <xsl:call-template name="data"/> </xsl:result-document> and <xsl:result-document format="no_indent" > <xsl:call-template name="data"/> </xsl:result-document>

Comment: I will take a look when I get home.